# How to add success message when registration is completed

Tags: php, html, sql

How do i make an success message when form is submitted

here is the code:

**server.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = "";
$errors = array(); 

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'reg_user');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);


  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }


  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }
  }


  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: register.php');
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="card-body">
              <p><?php include('errors.php'); ?></p>
                <form method="POST" action="register.php" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" name="username" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                  </div>
```

here is the code of error.php which it pops up a error message when username is taken
**error.php**

```
<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button>
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
      <p><center><b><?php echo $error ?></center></b></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
  </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

I want to add success message just like the error.php but what is the code to perform an success message?

Comment: You do not have error.php in your code. You likely meant `header('location: thanks.php'); } else { header('location: error.php');}`

Comment: the code in error.php is ok it echo the error message but i dont know how do i display successful message when form is submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
if (!$errors)
{
    header("Location: success.php");
    exit;
}
```

or modify this part from your code:

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
          VALUES('$username', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = TRUE;
    header('location: success.php'); exit;
}
```

Comment: i want to pop up the success message just like where the error.php were placed

Comment: I just edited my code before your comment, recheck please.

Comment: i re edit my problem i put the error.php can you check it out? i want it to be same as successful message

Comment: That's wrong, Success message should not be the same like error message, error message will show above the register form, but if success, then why we should show the success message above the form? we should redirect the user to another page (this also will avoid you the double insert to your user table), or you will need to re construct your code to hide the form and add some conditions to avoid the miss of double insert and re-post of your data.

Comment: check the logic please.

Comment: is it possible to echo $_SESSION['success'] message when form is successfully put in the database? just like error message when the username were already taken the error message will pop up

Comment: yes, that's true, `!$errors`, `$_SESSION['success']`  or `count($errors) == 0` are the same mean, but what will happen after the user send his info?? you are showing him the registeration form again.

Comment: If errors we will show him the registration form again, but with success, then why we are doing that?

Comment: if the info were correct it will pop up a message above the username just like in my code, and all i want is just to put a "Registration Successful" on the same page when the user successfully registered

Comment: You should hide the registration form on success then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php if($_SESSION['success'] != '' ) : ?>
    <label> <?php include('success.php'); ?></label>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i want to pop up the success message just like where the error.php were placed

Comment: I just edited my answer now. You can have success.php similar to error.php and then write a condition in index.php like this to include the success.php file.